# How detect HTML audio ended on using Selenium Edgedriver on Excel VBA

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

I opened this page's Example by Excel VBA Selenium Edgedriver

i want to auto close edge browser auto audio is ended

so i searched for JavaScript...? Event Listener to apply my VBA Code

But i founded JAVA Code, I dont know i how to do....
help me plese..

```
my code

sub edGe()
    Dim edGe As New EdgeDriver
    
    With edGe
        .Start
        .Get "http://sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3"

    ' How i auto close if audio is ended....? 

End Sub
```

i founded html5 audio elements
http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

may i use "ended" event name..?

i found
edGe.FindElementById() something
but i don't how to input html Code...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I apologize for not being able to express it in detail. I'm making a vocabulary book with VBA. I even extracted a link to a voice file from a site called Wordreference, but I wrote this code to play the link in Excel. I initially tried to download the .wav file to my PC, but this is not possible due to the security program in the company, so I want to run the Internet directly and play it. However, even though the link is successful, there is a problem that the Internet window shuts down before it is fully played. That's why I'm posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ended event of the HTML5 audio element.  Add an event listener to that audio element for the ended event. When this event triggers, execute JavaScript to close the browser window.

```
Sub edGe()
    Dim edGe As New EdgeDriver
    Dim audioElement As WebElement
    Dim jsScript As String

    With edGe
        .Start
        .Get "http://sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3"

        .Wait 5000 'for 5 seconds

        ' Locate the audio element
        Set audioElement = .FindElementByTag("audio")

        ' Check if the audio element was found
        If Not audioElement Is Nothing Then
            ' Add an event listener for the 'ended' event to close the browser
            jsScript = "var audio = arguments[0];" & _
                       "audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {" & _
                       "    window.close();" & _
                       "});"
            
            .ExecuteScript jsScript, audioElement
        End If

        ' Keep the VBA script running, till closing the window
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm off work now, so I'll study and apply it one by one when I get back to work. Thank you very much.