# Wait Until addEventListener Selenium, Excel VBA

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I'm making a vocabulary book with VBA. I even extracted a link to a voice file from a site called Wordreference, but I wrote this code to play the link in Excel. I initially tried to download the .wav file to my PC, but this is not possible due to the security program in the company, so I want to run the Internet directly and play it. However, even though the link is successful, there is a problem that the Internet window shuts down before it is fully played.

```vb
Sub edGe()
    Dim edGe As New EdgeDriver
    
    With edGe
        .Start
        .Get "http://sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3"

    Set videoElement = .FindElementByTag("video")

   If Not videoElement Is Nothing Then
          jsScript = "const video = document.querySelector('video');" & _
                          "video.addEventListener('ended', function(){" & _ 
                           "console.log('video stopped');" & _    ' // it works on Edge development Console
                          window.close();" & _ 
                        ~"});" ' // It doesn't Work Error → Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.
 
           .ExecuteScript jsScript, videoElement
    End If

    End With
    

   ' So i wrote new code
   ' But i dont know how to do get EventListener On VBA Code ... 
     t = Timer 
     Do
           DoEvents
           On Error Resume Next
           Set ele = .FindElementByName("ended"
          On Error GoTo 0
         If Timer - t = 10 Then Exit Do <== To infinite loop
     Loop While ele Is Nothing

End Sub
```

My Previous Question
[How detect HTML audio ended on using Selenium Edgedriver on Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77323345)

I refer to
[Selenium Webdriver (VBA): Explicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956889/selenium-webdriver-vba-explicit-wait)

and also
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event